# Magento join query with having collection count mismatch

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, collection, query

I joined a custom table with the customer table applying a `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING` statement.

**The Code:**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join(
    array('review' => 'flrating'),
    "e.entity_id = review.reviewed_user_id "
);
$collection->getSelect()->group('review.reviewed_user_id');
$collection->getSelect()->having('AVG(review.avg_rating) >= ?', $min)
    ->having('AVG(review.avg_rating) <= ?', $max);
```

**The Query:**

This code is generating the following SQL:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `review`.* FROM `customer_entity` AS `e`
    INNER JOIN `flrating` AS `review` ON e.entity_id = review.reviewed_user_id
WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1') AND (`e`.`group_id` = '5')
GROUP BY `review`.`reviewed_user_id`
HAVING (AVG(review.avg_rating) >= '0') AND (AVG(review.avg_rating) <= '2')
```

When I do `Zend_Debug::dump($collection->getData())` it returns empty.

When I execute the query it shows an empty result, but when I put this query into PhpMyAdmin it shows two records (this is the correct result).

Also see see the below attached screens:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does `echo $collection->getSelect();` return the same SQL?

Comment: The Query is:- SELECT `e`.*, `review`.* FROM `customer_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `flrating` AS `review` ON e.entity_id = review.reviewed_user_id WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1') AND (`e`.`group_id` = '5') GROUP BY `review`.`reviewed_user_id` HAVING (AVG(review.avg_rating) >= '0') AND (AVG(review.avg_rating) <= '2')

Comment: `zend_debug::dump($collection->getData())` return empty?

Comment: no its not empty, its returning the two records data

Comment: Most likely need more details on your frontend approach (.phtml) files, etc.

Comment: but in the above query(if i change the range value means it will return the expected results in .phtml file) SELECT e.*, review.* FROM customer_entity AS e INNER JOIN flrating AS review ON e.entity_id = review.reviewed_user_id WHERE (e.entity_type_id = '1') AND (e.group_id = '5') GROUP BY review.reviewed_user_id HAVING (AVG(review.avg_rating) >= '0') AND (AVG(review.avg_rating) <= '4'),

Comment: Can you please add all the queries to the question instead commenting, so we can read it? But we need a comment so we are notified that something change :-)